# Are too many views in XML bad?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

I have an XML file with about 150 views. Yes, I know it is a lot and I did get a message from Android Studio saying I can't exceed 80 views. But I can't drop views any lower than 150. I considered using list view but it works the way I wanted it to.

The question is, will this many views make the app crash/slow the device? I've tried it on my s7 and it works perfectly fine. My lowest API is 17 which is 4.2. Wouldn't 4.2 devices be able to handle this XML without any problem?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with having an excessively large number of `View`s is that Android often needs to measure, layout, and draw them, and it will traverse the entire View hierarchy to do this. If the number of `View`s is so large that this traversal takes more time than the screen refresh rate, you will skip frames and your UI might appear to lag or be choppy.

If not all of those `View`s need to be on screen at once (for example, if you are using a `ScrollView` to hold a very large container that the user can scroll through), then you should probably switch to using `RecyclerView`.

If all of those views need to be on screen at once, then you might consider writing custom `View`s that can display your content all at once instead of having individual `View`s that draw individual things. This can drastically reduce the time and complexity of the measure/layout/draw traversals.

It's difficult to suggest an approach without knowing more specifics about your UI, but hopefully that explains the issue.

Comment: I am using scroll view. SOrry forgot to mention that. I will have to learn how to use RecyclerView as you suggested. Thank you so much.